# Nodejs readable-stream vs array.map

Tags: node.js, theory, nodejs-stream

In studying streams, the following example was provided:

```
  const data = ['some', 'data', 'to', 'read']
  const { Readable } = require('stream')
  const readable = Readable.from(data)
  readable.on('data', (data) => { console.log('got data:', data) })
  readable.on('end', () => { console.log('finished reading') })
```

This of course outputs `got data: some` followed by `got data: data` and so on and so forth for each array element.

I understand why a tutorial would use a simple example; however, I am struggling to imagine real world use cases for this snippet.

Speaking for the basic utility of the statement, it seems like no more than an obfuscation for any other way to loop over an array:

```
  // eg.
  const data = ['some', 'data', 'to', 'read']
  data.map(data => console.log('got data:', data));
```

I see the benefit of the second being brevity and the con for the prior being complexity. However, the second snippet lacks flexibility for binding stream events. What other information is useful to help understand when and in what cases to implement a read stream in this way?

Please share a code snippet that makes use of the readable stream (from an array or otherwise) in a way that demonstrates the power of the flexibility. Also share any notes that explain better why a readable stream would be more useful in this or other cases.

Comment: A stream is comparable to an array of data chunks, the difference with an array is all the chunks are not all present in the object at the start, they arrive one by one

Comment: @kaddath that's a useful perspective. would you go as far as saying there is no reason to use a readable stream on an existing array that is present at the start?

Comment: yes, abolutely, that's why the handling of streams is based on event handlers, for an array you don't need them as you already know where it ends and everything is accessible right now, a loop is enough

Comment: Another useful distinction is that it's like an array where read chunks are deleted from the array once read, so that typically you don't need to have all in memory. This allows to for exemple pipe a buffer stream to a file stream to save in a file without need to load everything and save memory

Answer (score 0):

**#some more example**

```
 const { Readable, Transform, pipeline } = require('stream');
    
    // Create an array of objects
    const data = [
      { name: 'Alice', age: 25 },
      { name: 'Bob', age: 30 },
      { name: 'Charlie', age: 28 },
    ];
    
    // Create a Readable stream from the array
    const readable = Readable.from(data);
    
    // Create a Transform stream to modify the data
    const transformStream = new Transform({
      objectMode: true,
      transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        chunk.age++; // Increment age for each object
        callback(null, chunk);
      },
    });
    
    // Pipe the readable stream through the transform stream and log the modified data
    pipeline(
      readable,
      transformStream,
      process.stdout, // Output to the console
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
        } else {
          console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: `data.map(person => person.age++);`